# cassandra UpdateColumnFamily InvalidRequestException Default TException

Tags: cassandra

I am using thrift-0.7.0 with cassandra-1.1.1 ,I was sucessfull in adding a new columnfamily with system_add_column_family,but when i try to add a new column to a existing columnfamily with system_update_column_family gives me an error "UpdateColumnFamily InvalidRequestException  Default TException", the sample  c++ code which i tried is as follows

```
string sReturn;
CfDef ColumnFamilyDef;
ColumnFamilyDef.keyspace="keyspace2";
ColumnFamilyDef.column_type="Standard";
ColumnFamilyDef.name="ColFM1";
ColumnFamilyDef.__isset.column_type=true;

ColumnDef column;
column.name="Col2";
column.validation_class="UTF8Type";
ColumnFamilyDef.column_metadata.push_back(column);

ColumnFamilyDef.__isset.column_metadata=true;
mpClient->system_update_column_family(sReturn,ColumnFamilyDef);
```

give me the following Exception

UpdateColumnFamily InvalidRequestException  Default TException

Can any one help me
Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your Cassandra log say?

Comment: Are you sure that `ColFM1` previously exists in your keyspace? Incase you are on a linux box try `tail -f your_cassandra_log_dir/system.log`  and execute this c code in other terminal

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still need to call `set_keyspace` on your connection to set it to your new keyspace prior to creating the column family.  That's perhaps what is breaking.

As a side note, this would probably be much easier to do using CQL rather than the old Thrift API.  You can basically just call `execute_cql_query` and pass in a string.  There's a [full reference for CQL](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index#cql-reference) that should make things easier.